# Different way to pass untrusted data into a Javascript script?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a Javascript function that retrieves data from the form `onClick` via the submission button.

```
 function valueCheck()
 {
            var cCheck = document.getElementById("c");
            var cChoice = chemCheck.options[chemCheck.selectedIndex].value;

            var coCheck = document.getElementById("co");
            var coChoice = compCheck.options[compCheck.selectedIndex].value;

            var gCheck = document.getElementById("g");
            var gChoice = geoCheck.options[geoCheck.selectedIndex].value;

            var mCheck = document.getElementById("m");
            var mChoice = mathCheck.options[mathCheck.selectedIndex].value;

            var pCheck = document.getElementById("p");
            var pChoice = physCheck.options[physCheck.selectedIndex].value;
```

According to [OSWAP XSS PREVENTION CHEAT SHEET](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) this is unsafe. The data is 'sanitized' using `filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)` and I `trim()` it as well for good measure. Unfortunately, this is server-side so it doesn't help. Right now there is a vulnerability if someone were to change the values in the select menu. I call my Javascript function like so:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onClick="return function();">
```

It needs to be able to work client-side. How can I filter/sanitize the data before I pass it to my Javascript function? I need to get each value in the select boxes so I can make sure they aren't the same. (Note the whole function isn't shown above, I can provide it if needed. I think the issue is mainly the way I put the data into the script).

How can I escape the data?

EDIT: To clarify my question, I am wondering if there is a secure method to passing client-side data to a javascript function. This data hasn't been sanitized yet (besides all the client-side stuff I can do to it) so I'm worried that there may be an XSS vulnerability.  According to the OSWAP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet I'm supposed to escape data, but I am not too sure how to do this as well. I do not render any user-inputted data into the browser, it is only stored.

EDIT2: I think I finally understand. The XSS vulnerabilities mentioned in the OSWAP cheatsheet refer to placing user-given data into HTML/other things and displaying it back to the page? If I'm only saving this to text files/csv files I think I'd just have to make sure everything is good server-side.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. You get data from form via JavaScript and what you do with it ? Where is the problem ?

Comment: The issue is the way I retrieve the data. According to the article, it is unsafe to pass unsafe data into a script. Unless I am wrong, I'm still trying to learn about XSS.

Comment: What is the flow of your data ? Client side -> server side -> client side ?

Comment: Client side -> Server side. All these forms really do is collect the data via forms and store it in text/csv files. However, these forms are going to be placed on a website later.

Comment: As I understand it, you are concerned too much. User comes to your page, fills in values, javascript is executed in user's browser. User would have to actively try to hack himself. Only when you redisplay the form, eg because of failed validation, you need to be concerned with XSS.

Comment: @Marek, Haha that makes me feel a bit better about my security concerns. If the form fails, it echoes a hardcoded message in PHP and then redirects to another page. They can turn Javascript off, but the form will not display. I was just kinda worried since the user can easily change the values in the select menu. However I implemented a check on the server-side to see if it was anything other than the values listed (they are only numbers 0-5), so it works out pretty well serverside. It just replaces it with 'Invalid' if it is anything else.

Comment: If you only store data, there is no XSS vulnerability. End of strory. However, you should still check input data length if you don't want someone to put 10TB of data into your server.

Comment: @Scony, Thank you very much, that's great news. I also do check input length client-side, the `maxlength=""`feature comes in handy. I suppose I should limit the length of things server-side as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only store data, there is no XSS vulnerability. End of strory. However, you should still check input data length if you don't want someone to put 10TB of data into your server.

Generally client-side is an illusion. HTML and JavaScript are like curtain that covers real code of your webapp (php or whatever you got on server side). You can **never** trust client side data, even if you filter it with JS. Someone can basically turn off JS or use some other software than browser to comunicate with your website (like netcat or curl).

I recommend you to watch [this whole movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRJpWyLnZv4) so you can imagine way hackers will hack you.

Remember, **filter input/output data server side**.